# Loading and appending new data (in X,Y format) to existing layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, layers, attribute-table, append

I have a daily task where I need to loads and append 25 points into the same  QGIS layer. Can anybody guide me, how to achieve this task?

Currently it loads and replace the data in the existing layer but I want to append it.

In ArcMap, this tool is called *Load*, but I need it in QGIS.

Comment: How will you have the X,Y data? Is it a CSV? What happens to the existing points in the layer?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using **AppendFeaturesToLayer** plugin in QGIS. This is a processing plugin-based provider for QGIS 3 that adds will append features to a desired vector layer.

Please see [this github page](https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer), for more details and how this plugin works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Load and append** Solution：

1. Add x,y data, save to shp.
2. Merge two shp (new shp and old shp).

[image: Vector -> Data Management tools -> merge shapefile to one]